# Arrange equation in normal form

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-construction

Is there a way, or if not, how could one define a function which takes an equation in any form (for example as given by `FullSimplify`):

$$(A+X_0) x+By=3x$$

and rearranges it in the more compact and tidy form:

$$(A+X_0-3) x+By=0$$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d, x, y]
expr = a x + b y + c x == d x;
```

You can use any of

```
Collect[(expr /. Equal -> Subtract) == 0, x]
Collect[Subtract @@ expr == 0, x]
FullSimplify[(expr /. Equal -> Subtract) ] == 0 
FullSimplify[Subtract @@ expr] == 0
```

to get

```
(* (a + c - d) x + b y == 0 *)
```

Alternatively, use a custom [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) that makes non-zero expressions on the right-hand-side of `==` more *expensive*:

```
cf[e_] := 100 Count[e, Equal[_, Except[0, _]], {0, Infinity}] + LeafCount[e]
FullSimplify[expr, ComplexityFunction -> cf]
(* (a + c - d) x + b y == 0 *)
```

**Update:** In versions 11.3+, you can use the function [`SubtractSides`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubtractSides.html):

```
FullSimplify /@ SubtractSides[expr]
```

> ```
>  (a + c - d) x + b y == 0
> ```

Comment: A very nice solution, that is with the complexity function.

Comment: @kglr Hi! In v11.3 and wolframcloud, `FullSimplify / @ SubtractSides[expr]` can not run. Syntax: "FullSimplify cannotbe followedby@SubtractSide $\{$ expr'].

Comment: Thank you @lotus2019; the typo is fixed.

Comment: @kglr My pleasure.