# Moving certain variables to one side of the equation

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I am having trouble moving certain variables from one side of the equation to the other. 
For example, if i want to solve for `x1`:

```
Reduce[x1 + x2 + x3 == 4, x1]
```

> ```
> x1 == 4 - x2 - x3
> ```

but if i want to solve for 2 variables (`x1` and `x2`):

```
Reduce[x1 + x2 + x3 == 4, {x1, x2}]
```

> ```
> x2 == 4 - x1 - x3
> ```

But what I need is

> ```
> x1 + x2 == 4 - x3
> ```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: related: [Arrange equation in normal form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76316/125)

Comment: You can simply: `Reduce[u + x3 == 4, u] /. u -> x1 + x2`

Comment: related: [Is it possible to have Mathematica move all terms to one side of an equation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4954/245)

Comment: You can modify [my answer to the question I linked above](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4957/245), to get the desired result: `eqn = x1 + x2 + x3 == 4; Map[Subtract[#, First[eqn] - (x1 + x2)] &, eqn]`. Alternatively, `Distribute[eqn - (First[eqn] - (x1 + x2)), Equal]`. Also, I think the other linked question, [Arrange equation in normal form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76316/245), is a duplicate of the earlier one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not perfect nor general but probably useful enough:

```
solveMany[expr_, vars_List] := Module[{u},
  (Plus @@ vars) == u /. Solve[
     Eliminate[{ expr, Plus @@ vars == u}, vars],
     u][[1]]
  ]
```

And for example:

```
solveMany[x1 + x2 + x3 == 4, {x1, x3}]
```

> ```
> x1 + x3 == 4 - x2
> ```