# Arranging sides of an equation

Tags: equation-solving, code-request

I have to create my own function to solve equations (first and second degree). Assuming you have any input equation, how can I do to bring everything to the first side of the equation?

Example. I have:

```
eq=3*x+2==-2*x^2+4
```

but I'd like to have:

```
eq=2*x^2+3*x-2==0
```

Thanks.

Comment: `(Subtract @@ eq) == 0` should work.

Comment: Closely related: [Does Mathematica have a built-in tool that allows one to operate on both sides of an equation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86906/5478)

Comment: I use the similar (eq /. Equal -> Subtract) == 0, which will work at any level of a list

Comment: @KraZug thanks for solution !!

Comment: Actually I should have said that (eq /. Equal -> Subtract) works at any level of the list, but setting it to be equal to 0 would need Thread applying at the appropriate levels. If you just want the left hand side it works fine.

Comment: related Q/A: [Arrange equation in normal form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76316/125)

Comment: Special case of [Is it possible to have Mathematica move all terms to one side of an inequality?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4954/245)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use Equal -> Subtract to move from equalities to having everything on the left hand side, i.e.

```
(eq /. Equal -> Subtract)
-2 + 3 x + 2 x^2
```

If you want them to back to equations then here is a function that will allow it to be applied at any level of a list (rather than needing to use Thread):

```
rearrangeLeft[a_, b_] := a - b == 0
rearrangeLeftApply[x_] := x /. Equal -> rearrangeLeft
```

So applying to a nested list:

```
rearrangeLeftApply[{eq, {eq}, {{{eq}}}}]
{-2 + 3 x + 2 x^2 == 0, {-2 + 3 x + 2 x^2 == 0}, {{{-2 + 3 x + 2 x^2 == 0}}}}
```

Comment: Incidentally I'm terrible at naming functions, and couldn't figure out how to write the Apply function without defining the intermediate function