# How to rearrange both sides of a polynomial equation?

Tags: polynomials

I  wonder  that  which  command  can  rearrange  one  side  of  a  equation  into  0,  e.g.  "ax==by"  into  "ax-by==0".

Comment: closely related/possible duplicate Q/A: [Arrange equation in normal form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76316/125)

Comment: `# - eqn[[-1]] & /@ eqn`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways:

```
#1 - #2 == 0 & @@ (a x == b y)

(* a x - b y == 0 *)


#[[1]] - #[[2]] == 0 &@ (a x == b y)

(* a x - b y == 0 *)
```

As far as I can tell, they're going to work on any equation, with no modification. And it's straightforward to define

```
lhsequals0 = #[[1]] - #[[2]] == 0 &
```

so that, for example

```
lhsequals0[3 x^2 + 2 y - 4 == 6 xy^2 - 4 x^2 + Cos[Sqrt[y]]]

(* -4 + 7 x^2 - 6 xy^2 + 2 y - Cos[Sqrt[y]] == 0 *)
```

Just to give a sense of how and why this works, look at the `FullForm` for your equation:

```
FullForm[a x == b y]

(* Equal[Times[a, x], Times[b, y]] *)
```

An equation will always have the head `Equal`, with the first argument (`#[[1]]` or `#1`, depending) being the lhs and the second (`#[[2]]` or `#2`) being the rhs. So all both of the above functions are doing is subtracting the rhs from the lhs and setting `Equal` to zero.

Do see @kglr's link in the comments for some more in-depth answers.

Comment: Thanks aardvark2012! your way seems elegant.

Comment: @HC6 Realised I was needlessly complicating it. Fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

> "ax==by" into "ax+by==0".

I assume you meant `a x - b y ==0` in the above.

One way (out of many I am sure) is

```
ClearAll[x,y,a,b,lhs,rhs];
eq=a x==b y;
lhs=eq/.(lhs_==rhs_)-> lhs;
rhs=eq/.(lhs_==rhs_)-> rhs;
eq=lhs-rhs==0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oh, silly me! I do mean "ax-by==0"

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread) on [`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal):

```
eqn = a x == b y;

Thread[eqn - b y, Equal]
```

> a x - b y == 0

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  However, the actual case is a bit more complicated, where both sides is not konwn, and your solution might be not so easy to carry out.

Answer (score 3):

Since V 12.3 we have `SubtractSides` and other related functions.

```
f = a x == b y;

SubtractSides[f, b y]
```

a x - b y == 0

Answer (score 1):

A minor rephrasing of the existing answers:

```
f1 = a x == b y;
f2 = 3 x^2 + 2 y - 4 == 6 xy^2 - 4 x^2 + Cos[Sqrt[y]];

Subtract @@ # == 0 & /@ {f1, f2}
```

> {a x - b y == 0, -4 + 7 x^2 - 6 xy^2 + 2 y - Cos[Sqrt[y]] == 0}